# Datastore for Images on Google App Engine sent by Android Client

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

The question is very specific to which of the two storage options on Google App Engine will be a better solution for my Android Application that has to store and retrieve images from the server (google apps engine)

1. High Replication Data Storage - Use the Blobstore Api to work around it.
2. Use Google Cloud Sql - Create Relational Data Storage in the Cloud.

I am new to Google Apps Engine so not sure about the decision. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You. Hope to hear soon.

Comment: How can we possibly answer this question? The best option depends on your requirements, but you haven't mentioned what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have several options:

1. [Blob property in Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types): simplest to use, but limited to 1Mb. Price of storage $0.12/GB/month
2. [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview): similar to Blob in DB: simple to use, effectively limited to 32Mb (max HTTP response size). Price of storage $0.12/GB/month
3. [Imageservice](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Using_the_Images_Service_with_the_Blobstore): can sit in front of Blobstore, helping you to cache and resize images (important if you want to optimize images for mobile devices).
4. Cloud SQL - a MySQL database shoehorned into GAE. I wouldn't use this as it's expensive: storage $0.24/GB/month, traffic $0.12/GB/month (in addition to your frontend instance traffic).
5. [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/): external service, but integrated with GAE (has direct API). More features, access controls, etc. Harder to use, [lower price](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/cloud-storage): storage $0.085/GB/month.

Note: all services will cost you $0.12/GB of network bandwidth. The only way to lower this is to use caching (but this then requires to have public Urls).

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter it is helpful.It will be really helpful in making the decision now